# My yum repository able to search packages, but not able to install it in RHEL?

Tags: linux, installation, yum, packages, gcc

I set up `yum` from  dvd. Following is the containts of my `.repo` file:

```
[dvd]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux Installation DVD
baseurl=file:///media/dvd
enabled=0.
```

I'm able to search packages. However while installation I'm getting below error:

```
[root@localhost dvd]# yum install libstdc++.x86_64
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
```

My Yum Search output:

```
[root@localhost dvd]# yum search gcc
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
============================================================================= Matched: gcc =============================================================================
compat-libgcc-296.i386 : Compatibility 2.96-RH libgcc library
compat-libstdc++-296.i386 : Compatibility 2.96-RH standard C++ libraries
compat-libstdc++-33.i386 : Compatibility standard C++ libraries
compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64 : Compatibility standard C++ libraries
cpp.x86_64 : The C Preprocessor.
libgcc.i386 : GCC version 4.1 shared support library
libgcc.x86_64 : GCC version 4.1 shared support library
libgcj.i386 : Java runtime library for gcc
libgcj.x86_64 : Java runtime library for gcc
libstdc++.i386 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libstdc++.x86_64 : GNU Standard C++ Library
libtermcap.i386 : A basic system library for accessing the termcap database.
libtermcap.x86_64 : A basic system library for accessing the termcap database.
```

Please guide me on this, I want to install `gcc` on my `RHEL`.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `enabled=0` to `enabled=1`.

> Set enable=0 in a definition file to prevent yum from using that repository. The yum utility ignores any definition file with this setting.

---

When you enabled the repo you got the following error message

> file:///media/dvd/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No
>   such file or directory: '/media/dvd/repodata/repomd.xml' Trying other
>   mirror. Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for
>   repository: dvd. Please verify its path and try again

Which suggests that your dvd isn't mounted or if it is mounted, then it is mounted somewhere other than `/media/dvd`

Comment: With `enabled=1`, I even not able to search the packages also. I'm getting below error: `[root@localhost dvd]# yum install libstdc++.x86_64
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
file:///media/dvd/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 5] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/dvd/repodata/repomd.xml'
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: dvd. Please verify its path and try again
`

Comment: @mandy You didn't mount the DVD at `/media/dvd` so `yum` couldn't find it. Try again.

Comment: Now, It shows following informtion/error: `[root@localhost media]# yum install cpp.x86_64
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem in one of two ways. Choose one:

1. Pay for your Red Hat subscription and register the machine on Red Hat Network.
2. Use a RHEL clone such as CentOS.